# How to set up custom automatic character replacement in emacs ess?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

One of the useful features of `ess-mode` (Emacs speaks statistics) is to automatically replace the underscore `_` with the assignment operator `<-`. Lately, I have been using a lot of pipes (written as `%>%`) and it would be great to not have to type three characters for each pipe.

Is it possible to define a custom key binding for the pipe, similar to the one converting `_` into `->`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to just bind a key to insert a string:

```
(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "|") "%>%")
```

You can still insert `|` with `C-q |`.  I'm not sure about the map's name; you'll almost certainly want to limit the key binding to `ess-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet). You can use it to define something like "if this sequence of characters is followed by this key (which you can define to whatever you like), then replace them with this other sequence of characters and leave the cursor in this place". There's more to `yasnippet` than this, but there's plenty of documentation online and even already made recipes similar to the example I gave above that you can try, like [yasnippet-ess-mode](https://github.com/mattfidler/yasnippet-ess-mode), for example.

Alternatively, you can also try [abbrev-mode](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_abbrev_mode_tutorial.html) and see if that works for you.

I, for one, like `yasnippet` better, since you can also specify where to leave the cursor after the expansion, but `abbrev-mode` seems to be easier to set up. As always in Emacs world, try multiple solutions, don't settle for the first one you put your hands on. What works best for others might not work for you, and vice-versa.